# How to remove post in PagingDataAdapter android

Tags: android, android-paging-3

Android Paging library 3 (3.1.1)

I have implemented the paging3 library for Shortlisting posts. I am showing the shortlisted post in recycler view with paging, and it's working fine.

Now I want to remove a post from the list.

I looked at this issue on git but have not found any issue.

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/281

Help， please

Comment: If you're using room it's easy otherwise you've to submit newlist or manage with notifyItemRemved

Comment: @GobuCSG if I submit a new list then it affects my pagination and I tried to manage with notifyItemRemoved but it didn't work. 

mainListAdapter.snapshot().toMutableList().apply { removeAt(position) }
            mainListAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

Comment: toMutableList Make new list.

Comment: Snapshot() is an immutable list how to remove items from that?

Comment: Remove then submit the list to diffutill automatically update your view

Comment: every item when user unshort any post I need to submit list again ?

Comment: https://link.medium.com/IOWt4gULrrb try this

Comment: @GobuCSG notifyItemChanged is working for me also but when I try to use notifyItemRemoved it just removes the item and then adds a new one with the same attributes.

Comment: mainListAdapter.snapshot().toMutableList().apply {
removeAt(position)
then submit this list to your livedata
}
 All the changes available in your data class mean Diffutill callback won't affect your changes..